# How to fetch data from gridview in ItemTemplate in ASP.NET 2

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, itemtemplate

I have a gridview where each columns have two template fields. One is ItemTemplate and another is EditItemTemplate. Now in EditItemTemplate it will show some textboxes where i can perform necessary editing. I can easily fetch data from each cell by using the following code-

```
Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = gvView.Rows(e.RowIndex)

CType(gvRow.FindControl("controlID"), TextBox).Text
```

But how can i fetch data when the grid view is not in editing mode that is in ItemTemplate. I have tried the following-

```
Dim rowView As DataRowView = CType(gvRow.DataItem, DataRowView)

Dim something As String = rowView("data_field").ToString()
```

But its getting the exception object reference is not set to an instance of object. This is probably happening because the above code should be used in a method like RowDataBound when a row is instantiated. But I have to fetch data from some other method. Any idea how to do this.

Again for clarification I want to fetch data when the gridview columns are in ItemTemplate Mode.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to read value of grid view column in some command. If you have `gvRow` which is your gridview's row then you can use `.Cell(index).Text` in order to get value of the column.

If you are using template field and using some controls to show column data, you have to do `gvRow.findControl("controlId")` and then cast it to appropriate control object to read data from it.

Happy coding

Comment: Nope I have tried that. Whatever I do .Cell(index).Text returns "" . That is an empty string.

Comment: which event are you using? please post the aspx and vb/cs code here, so that we can help a lot

Comment: I am using the onClick event. The whole code cannnot be given. Just look at the following line. What Am I doing wrong ?? Dim test As String= Me.gvView.Rows(index).Cells(index).Text  though there is a value but I am ending up having test set to ""

Comment: Ok that makes sense, are you using any control to show column data? in that case you have to do Me.gvView.Rows(index).FindControl(ControlId) to get the control and then grab value from it

Comment: well i am using a control in the editItemTemplate but in itemTemplate I am using DataBinder. So how can I grab data when i am not in editing mode

Comment: I guess you need to add <asp:hiddenField into your column and find it by id, that's the easiest way to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

You may consider accessing the gridview datasource directly. Be careful when doing this if you allow sorting / paging on the grid as the index into your datasource will differ.

Answer (score -1):

Two answers worked fine thank you very much.

I spent more time trying to get the GridView Cell value but  useless I could not Know what is the problem. When I read your answer I found that my GridView has template fields so that was the problem.

Comment: This is not an answer ! this should be in the comment (if required)